# Public Database for Mobile Application

Tags: sql-server, security, architecture

What are the proper steps to hosting a public database. Currently I a building a mobile application with Adobe Flash Builder. I have used Microsoft SQL Server, My SQL as well as WAMP Server. All of these I have been told are private databases and thus will only allow my application to how the information as long as they are on the same internet connection. I have also been told that port forwarding my database isn't safe either.

In this case what is the best approach to making my database public or what other source should I use to make my application accessible to world wide users.

Answer (score 2):

For this scenario, the database server should not be publicly exposed, for obvious security reasons.

You should expose a public interface (API) of your application, probably by using something like web services. The mobile application instances then only communicate directly with the API.

This separation (decoupling) allows for all sorts of good things to happen, such as easier scale-out/load balancing.

Comment: This was great information , thank you. I have found a site that enables me to implement a production server. All I have to do is link my application with this server, would you agree with this ?

Comment: @rynwtts: From what you said, it's unclear what service is being provided, so I can't say I agree or disagree. Please clarify?

Comment: I was writing my application and testing with Microsoft Sql server, which was only giving me a development aspect of a server. I needed to find a production server online where I can upload my sql code, and connect the data to my application via the production server and not my local home server. I wanted to create an app that anyone would be able to trade information, and not have to be on my personal local server.

Comment: @rynwtts: Right. All you need to do is deploy your database to a hosting provider's SQL Server instance, and deploy the web application to their web server.